# JQL query for finding all epics with bugs linked to them

Tags: jira, issue-tracking, jql, jira-agile

I am trying to write a JQL query to list all bugs assigned to resolved epics. And I need to do without Script runner.
The filter I have for resolved epics for a particular duration is

`issuetype = epic AND status in ("In Progress", "Passed", Released) AND createdDate >= 2018-04-01 AND createdDate <= 2018-06-30`

I now want to use the output from this query and filter for `issueType=Bug` linked to them.

I tried options mentioned in this suggestion for allowing nested JQL calls https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRASERVER-21936 but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's currently no way to do this with JQL without an add-on.

Answer (score 0):

We are managing to do this with a two dimensional filter on a dashboard.

Your JQL will need to contain all of your Epics which you want to see the Bugs in them, which can lead to a horrifically long string.

E.g.
issuetype = bug AND "Epic Link" in (XX-1404, XX-1403, XX-1401, XX-1400, XX-1399, XX-1398, YY-2716, YY-2689, YY-2687)

[image: Two Dimensional Widget Settings]